# How do I schedule for all the files of one folder to be moved to another server?

Tags: windows, vbscript, ftp, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I did a quick search and couldn't see anything that was relevant which I found strange as this seems like it'd be a common question. Maybe I'm just going the wrong way about it or being thick? Who knows.

Anyway, I am trying to set up a scheduled task that moves all the files in a folder from Server A to a folder in Server B. If this was a simple matter of copying them it would be fine as I'd already got that working using Core FTP and a batch file but I'd like them to be removed from Server A after the copy has taken place.

I was looking at the windows ftp commands but although I managed to log onto Server A successfully from Server B whenever I tried to do a command it just took a very long time and then disconnected.

Any help in this would be appreciated, I need it to be a schedule-able file but it doesn't matter whether it is a .bat, .vbs or anything else that I haven't though of?

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Do you need to access the other server via FTP? If so, you'll need to fix whatever is wrong with your FTP server first, before you can do any kind of automated scripting. (Try [serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com/).) Otherwise, you're just talking about a move, rather than a copy. Can you do this from the Windows Command Prompt (i.e., are the computers on the same local network, and can one mount the network shares from the other)? If so, it's a simple manner to bang together a batch file.

Comment: The servers aren't connected locally so I thought FTP would be my best bet and it's possible to copy and delete files (which is essentially moving) with a program like Filezilla but sadly you can't schedule a task like that to be automated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use www.Dropbox.com

Why? For stability. Any home-brew ftp script that **moves** files, is prone to an undetected error in transmission, resulting in deleted files.